# Rethink DB Query use secondary index for unix time stamp value range

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to query or filter specific access logs for a give unix time stamps (start and end). However, using plain filter below takes forever to query.
There are more than 1M records in this table.

Also, there is a secondary index `unixTimestamp` which I want to use so that it would be a lot faster. My problem is how to use that secondary index `unixTimestamp` and perform the query like below?

**Rethink Query:**

```
r.db("my_db")
  .table("my_access_log")
  .filter(
    function(accessLog) {
      return accessLog("unixTimestamp").ge(1550660220)
        .and(accessLog("unixTimestamp").le(1550663580));
    }
  )
```

**Sample Data (Access log):**

```
{
    "access":  "Granted" ,
    "createdDateS":  "2019-02-19T18:17:01" ,
    "id":  "abc123" ,
    "sn":  "123413523523" ,
    "unixTimestamp": 1550563149 ,
    "user": dummyuser@dummies.com, »
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting the answer sooner, I needed the answer asap and found out myself... I just post it just in case someone would be having the same problem.

```
r.db("my_db")
  .table("my_access_log")
    .between(1550660220, 1550663580, {"index": "unixTimestamp"})
      .orderBy({index: r.desc('unixTimestamp')})
```

This is searching using secondary index `unixTimestamp` between unix time stamps `1550660220 (start)` and `1550663580 (end)`. Then sort the results in descending order by the field `unixTimestamp`.

If you need to filter by date... just replace the `between(start, end)` values.

With this, I was able to get the records immediately compared if I will not use the secondary index as my table has almost 2M records.

Hope this helps!